# Matching Groups in Bash

Tags: regex, bash

I am learning bash scripting and I am trying to understand how regex works with bash. In my simple program, I have a file of various different lines but want to match a simple int pair with the format of the two numbers separated by a comma and a space as so: 123, 123. I also want to match the line with groups so I can easily extract the first and last numbers from the line. But when I pass a sample file to my program, it doesn't match any of the lines that I expect.

code:

```
#!/bin/bash

re="([0-9]+)(, )([0-9]+)"

echo $1
file1=$1

while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "The line is: $line"
    if [[ $line =~ $re ]]; then
           echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]};
           echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]};
           echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]};
    fi
done < $1
```

sample.txt:

```
56, 345
Hello world 1234
Hello world, 1234
Hello world1234
BAd
Hello
Hello World
Hello dog
```

Expected output:

```
This line is: 56, 345
56
, 
This line is: Hello world 1234
This line is: Hello world, 1234
This line is: Hello world1234
This line is: BAd
This line is: Hello
This line is: Hello World
This line is: Hello dog
```

Actual output:

```
./asymmetrickey_encr keys.txt
./asymmetrickey_encr: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./asymmetrickey_encr: line 4: `re=([0-9]+)(, )([0-9]+)'
```

Comment: Is `[0=9]+` a typo?

Comment: Oops, sorry I did enter that typo for some reason... I 'll fix it right now

Comment: You don't seem to be reading from anything. Shouldn't that be `done < "$file1"`?

Comment: Thats right, I really messed up with the copying of my code, I ll fix it

Comment: You should also add your expected output (and what you get instead).

Comment: Thanks, I just added them

Comment: I can't reproduce this, your script works as expected for me. It'll also print `56, 345`, by the way, as that's what `${BASH_REMATCH[0]}` matches.

Comment: Why does it say "line 4"? It's line 3 in your code. What's different in your real code?

Comment: Ah. You're missing the quotes around your regex. You have them here, but not in your real code.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much, I can't believe I overlooked that.